# How to fix "peewee.InternalError: (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")" when data is inserted

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am inserting some data into Heroku MySQL database via peewee

```
Place.create(day="1", time="20", place="1")
```

and I get error

```
peewee.InternalError: (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")
```

I have found an answer which said that i need to turn off strict mode in MySQL, but it seems like it didn't work. I have also tried to add auto_increment to id, but looked pointless since it already had primary_key value

This is a booking app for a bar, i want to connect User model and Place model with Reservation model.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = CharField(unique=True)

class Place(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    day = CharField()
    time = CharField()
    pl = CharField()

class Reservation(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    u_id = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='reservs')
    p_id = ForeignKeyField(Place, backref='reservs')
```

And this piece of code loads data into Place. The last line gives me error.

```
for day in range(1,8):
    for time in range(18, 26, 2):
        for p in range(1, 9):
            Place.create(day=str(day), time=str(time), pl=str(p))
```

I have successfully inserted this into SQLite database locally, but it doesn't work with MySQL at Heroku at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `AutoField` instead of `IntegerField(primary_key=True)`. `AutoField` should be used when you want auto-incrementing integer primary key. `IntegerField(primary_key=True)` implies that you are explicitly specifying the integer value for the primary key, which is rarely what you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

The problem it's that you are not asigning any value to `id`. As `id` is a primary key, it is mandatory to have a value, and you didn't define a default value in case you don't provide it. You should change your code to something like this:

```
for day in range(1,8):
    for time in range(18, 26, 2):
        for p in range(1, 9):
            Place.create(id=id,day=str(day), time=str(time), pl=str(p))
```

You could also set the id column as autoincrement, so it would get the value  automatically

**EDIT**

If you need to set id, you can do it like this:

```
id=1
for day in range(1,8):
    for time in range(18, 26, 2):
        for p in range(1, 9):
            Place.create(id=id,day=str(day), time=str(time), pl=str(p))
            id=id+1
```

Comment: The correct answer is to use `AutoField` for auto-incrementing primary key. This answer is unhelpful.

Comment: Clearly you're upset I downvoted your (incorrect and unhelpful) answer.